# How can I switch focus between the various parts of vscode with the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, how to switch between the Explorer and the Editors, or between the Editors and the Terminal?

Comment: This is much broader than the "already has answers" question. Sorry it was closed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the short cuts:

- `Ctrl+0` : go to Explorer
- `Ctrl+1` : go to Editor Group 1
- `Ctrl+2` : go to Editor Group 2
- ....
- `Ctrl+9` : go to Editor Group 9

Comment: Ctrl+0 desn't seem to be built-in, at least on the Mac. I'll see if I can bind it as per the other answer.

Comment: @q.undertow for the mac subst `Cmd` for `Ctrl`

Comment: Perfect! Wanted to know this to be able to use keyboard to switch from search results back to editor. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and search for `Focus`. There are several commands to switch the focus, e.g. `View: Focus Active Editor Group` or `Explorer: Focus on Outline View`. You can assign custom keybindings to those.